# Error when calling stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here's my C# code

```
SqlCommand _dbTempCommand;
SqlDataAdapter _dbTempAdapter;

_dbTempCommand = new SqlCommand();
_dbTempCommand.Connection = this.DbSQLConnection;
_dbTempAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

_dbTempCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_dbTempCommand.CommandText = "spUserPOs";
_dbTempCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID",SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt16(EmpID);
_dbTempAdapter.Fill(_objAppData._dsPOTrackerDB_LocalCopy, "UserPOs");
```

And here's my SQL server stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUserPOs]
   @EmplopyeeID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT PO_No, PO_RaisedOn, PO_Date, PO_ExpDelDate, PO_Remarks, PO_Status, PO_SubTotalAmt, PO_TotalAmt, PO_VATRate, PO_ExpenseType, PO_CurrencyID, PO_DeliveryLocID
        FROM tbPO_header WHERE PO_Raisedby = @EmplopyeeID  ORDER BY PO_No;

END
```

When I run this I get an error as -

> Procedure or function 'spUserPOs' expects parameter '@EmployeeID',
>   which was not supplied.

I checked, the parameter is added with correct value.

Could someone please help resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a typo. You defined it `EmplopyeeID` in your stored procedure but you try to add it as `EmployeeID` in your parameter. `EmplopyeeID` vs `EmployeeID`. EmployeeID vs Emplo**p**yeeID. Unecessary `p` in your SP definition. I hope you see it.

Comment: You haven't added your command to adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously ?

Your stored procedure quotes a parameter name of "`EmplopyeeID`".

Your code is sending a parameter called "`EmployeeID`".

Spot the difference.

```
EmplopyeeID

EmployeeID
```

Comment: Strange that the sql error has the correct spelling.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I should have really spotted this :(